# Do we say "put your hair roller on your hair / head / bangs"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

Look at this picture

[image]

Do we say "**put your hair roller on your hair / head / bangs**"? But I didn't feel that a hair roller can be used in the same way as a hat or a hairband.

We can say "**put your hairband / hat on your head**" but for a hair roller we have to roll the hair on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put hair rollers **in** your hair.

"On" normally means "atop of" - like a hat sits on top of your head. When something is in amongst the hairs of your head, we use "in".

Comment: _Put your hair in rollers_ or _in curlers_ is also a possibility, at least in British English. The hair is _in_ the condition of being wound round the rollers to curl it.

Answer (score 0):

curler is a synonym of roller. According to OALD and Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English:

> She **put** her hear **in curlers** at night.
>   her hair was **in rollers/curlers**.